# Non-Qt Base Classes

Tags: c++, oop, qt

I'm using Qt (which I'm new to) 4.8.2, with Visual Studio, and I have created a base class named "Contact". **I don't want this class to be Qt-exclusive**, so my intention was to make another class "QContact" that will inherit "Contact", and QObject and deal with all the Qt-related business, such as the Q_OBJECT macro etc.

Unfortunately when I inherited, the build failed, saying:

```
moc_QContact.cpp(53): error C2039: 'staticMetaObject' : is not a member of 'Contact'
moc_QContact.cpp(75): error C2039: 'qt_metacast' : is not a member of 'Contact'
moc_QContact.cpp(80): error C2039: 'qt_metacall' : is not a member of 'Contact'
```

I did a little research on the web and found out that you can't derive a Qt class from non-Qt class. so to fix it, "Contact" could inherit "QObject" (I tried, it worked). but doing so will make it exclusive to Qt which is my problem.

So what I ask is this: How can you make a non-Qt base class for a Qt class?

Thank you.

Answer (score 104, accepted):

You can derive your class from `QObject` and from other classes that don't derive from it, but [`QObject` needs to be the first base class](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/moc.html#multiple-inheritance-requires-qobject-to-be-first) in the base classes list.

So this is wrong:

```
class QContact: public Contact, public QObject {};
```

You need to write it as

```
class QContact: public QObject, public Contact {};
```

Comment: That means the class will have no use outside Qt projects. there is no way around it?

Comment: @Ken i don't understand what that means. If `Contact` does not have anything todo with `QObject`, why will it "have no uses outside Qt projects"? Wasn't this your idea to archive that goal in the first place?

Comment: I'm sorry, I'll simplify:
I want "Contact" NOT to inherit from "QObject", because if I want to use it for other projects, I'll have the QObject base class stuck there, and that's an issue with non-Qt projects.

Comment: @Ken why do you think that `Contact` needs to derive from `QObject`?

Comment: As you mentioned: QObject needs to be the first base class. also from here: http://www.ffuts.org/blog/qt-staticmetaobject-is-not-a-member-of/

Comment: @Ken I think you are misunderstanding what I'm saying and what my link is saying. See the edit.

Comment: Oh, yes I have misunderstood. Thank you very much and sorry for bothering.

Comment: @Ken a small side: naming things QSomething makes it look like it's part of Qt API. It's a bit misleading (if I saw QContact in our code, I would start googling for it in the docs).

Comment: @suslik Granted, I namespaced it. Although, if you'd have a better naming for such cases I'd be happy to hear them. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

From [An Introduction To Design Patters in C++](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0132826453) with Qt Chapter 8.4:

To help ensure that moc processes
each QObject-derived class in the project, following are some guidelines for writing:
C++ code and qmake project files:

• Each class definition should go in its own .h file.

• Its implementation should go in a corresponding .cpp file.

• The header file should be “wrapped” (e.g., with #ifndef) to avoid multiple inclusion.
• Each .cpp file should be listed in the SOURCES variable of the project file;
otherwise it will not be compiled.

• Each header file should be listed in the HEADERS variable of the .pro file.
Without this, moc will not preprocess the file.

• The Q_OBJECT macro must appear inside the class definition of each QObject
derived header file so that moc knows to generate code for it.